# How do I prepare aging cedar siding for staining/painting?

Tags: siding

I have a home with old, somewhat damaged, cedar siding. I believe the siding was put on in the early 90s making it about 20 years old.  On more than one side there are places were you can see the pattern of what must have been some kind of trellis.

I'd like to re stain the siding so that is has a more even color.  What should I do to prepare the surface?

Comment: take a look at [this question](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/6703/3138), be sure to read the comments as well...

Answer (score 3):

If it's real cedar, it shouldn't be more complicated than scraping, sanding, and restaining.  You'll have to sand down to bare wood before restaining.  Depending on what kind of siding you have, it might be hard to sand it everywhere, in which case painting it might be a better option.  For paint, you just have to make sure you scrape/sand to the point where the paint has a good surface to adhere to.  Then prime and paint.

But you should make sure you know what you have.  Real wood is less and less common as siding, so you should make sure you don't have something like Hardiplank.

Comment: I wish I could include a photo ( need higher rep ).  The "damage" I mention is the part that makes me worried.  The grain of the wood is so raised that it feels almost like corduroy.